# Passport valid less than 3 months on Return travel

Tags: passports

I have an Indian passport valid till 25th Aug 2019. I am travelling from Atlanta(USA) to Bengaluru(India) via Paris with connection time of 3 hrs.
Return is on 23rd July 2019 from Bengaluru to Atlanta via Amsterdam with 3 hrs connection time.

During my return I will be renewing my passport.I have valid USA visa till 2020.

My question: will there be any issue in boarding flight in ATL ?

When I checked timatic: https://airfrance.traveldoc.aero/ by adding connecting flights, it says fine for ATL-CDG-BLR but for BLR-AMS-ATL, it says 'Passport expiry date must be 23 October 2019 or later (3 months after departure from Netherlands)'.

I am renewing passport on return. But will the airlines deny boarding because of the return ineligibility ?

Answer (score 1):

When returning to India, the 6 month before passport expiry doesn't count. So, you won't have any problems using the passport when travelling to India, as you are an Indian Citizen.

However, when going out of the country to USA, you need to renew (Which you are already planning to). So, there won't be any issues. Just make sure that the Visa is valid.

The Airlines won't consider whether you can return or not in the onward flight.